# translate first_value over partition by to linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am new to LINQ and it's still challenge to learn for people like me who is very used to normal SQL query.

I have the below query in SQL using sub query for left join and SQL server standard function like FIRST_VALUE, can this be translated into LINQ?
Not sure how can this first_value function can be re-written in LINQ..

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Stock

LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT distinct stockID, FIRST_VALUE(unitPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY stockid ORDER BY dbo.SalesOrder.orderDate desc ) last_unit_cost,
                             FIRST_VALUE(orderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY stockid ORDER BY dbo.SalesOrder.orderDate desc ) last_order_date

    FROM dbo.SalesOrderDetail 
    JOIN dbo.SalesOrder ON SalesOrder.salesOrderID = SalesOrderDetail.salesOrderID 
    WHERE customerID = 4
) x ON x.stockID = Stock.stockID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.First()` method it get the first element from a collection which implements `IEnumerable`.

An example:

```
int[] number = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
var num = number.Where(n => n > 10).First();
```

The where method looks into the number array and finds the values where the value is greater than 10.

This would return a collection with only 11 and then we get the first value which will return 11.

A great course is Linq Fundamental on Pluralsight by Scott Allen where you can find info about other operators like `FirstOrDefault` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't at all replicate the functionality of first_value in SQL Server.